# Performing conversions between data in different rows in different columns in R?

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Standard | 2 | NA |
| Data1 | NA | 4 |
| Data2 | NA | 8 |
| Data3 | NA | 16 |
| Standard | 3 | NA |
| Data4 | NA | 9 |
| Data5 | NA | 27 |
| Data6 | NA | 81 |

Ultimately, what I would like to do is to convert column C to another number based on a formula, using data from column B as a factor in said formula. Ideally, this would go in a 4th column (D).

The formula would be (B/16)*C, for all samples associated with that control value.

So the finished product would look something like:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Standard | 2 | NA | NA |
| Data1 | NA | 4 | X |
| Data2 | NA | 8 | X |
| Data3 | NA | 16 | X |
| Standard | 3 | NA | NA |
| Data4 | NA | 9 | X |
| Data5 | NA | 27 | X |
| Data6 | NA | 81 | X |

I've actually done this before many times, but always when column B was filled. I've never done calculations between rows with this setup.

A lot of the stuff I've seen walks folks through calculations where both columns are filled, but I'm a little stumped as to how to perform this conversion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you want to operate on each individual row of column C, using data from all rows of column B in some mathematical operation? That should be easy, maybe the NA values are causing an issue but you can bypass that, e.g. `df$D = df$C / mean(df$B, na.rm=T)` would divide each value of C by the mean value of column B, with `na.rm=T` ensuring that any NA values in B are omitted.

Comment: Please add the *formula* and an expected column D.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do - but if you want to fill with the nearest non-NA value above or below, you can use `fill` from package tidyr: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html

Comment: Formula and desired results table added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using `dplyr`.

I interpret the question that the formula should be applied in groups per `A == "Standard"`, therefore assuming a data set that is already ordered accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(log = A %in% "Standard", grp = cumsum(log)) %>% 
  mutate(D = ifelse(!is.na(C), (B[log]/16)*C, NA), .by = grp) %>% 
  select(-c(grp, log))
         A  B  C       D
1 Standard  2 NA      NA
2    Data1 NA  4  0.5000
3    Data2 NA  8  1.0000
4    Data3 NA 16  2.0000
5 Standard  3 NA      NA
6    Data4 NA  9  1.6875
7    Data5 NA 27  5.0625
8    Data6 NA 81 15.1875
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 library(tidyverse)
 df %>%
   fill(B)%>%
   mutate(D = B * C/16)

         A B  C       D
1 Standard 2 NA      NA
2    Data1 2  4  0.5000
3    Data2 2  8  1.0000
4    Data3 2 16  2.0000
5 Standard 3 NA      NA
6    Data4 3  9  1.6875
7    Data5 3 27  5.0625
8    Data6 3 81 15.1875
```

---

In Base R:

```
transform(df, D = B[cummax(seq_along(B)*!is.na(B))]*C/16)
         A  B  C       D
1 Standard  2 NA      NA
2    Data1 NA  4  0.5000
3    Data2 NA  8  1.0000
4    Data3 NA 16  2.0000
5 Standard  3 NA      NA
6    Data4 NA  9  1.6875
7    Data5 NA 27  5.0625
8    Data6 NA 81 15.1875
```

---

```
transform(df, D = B[which(!is.na(B))[cumsum(A=='Standard')]] * C/16)
         A  B  C       D
1 Standard  2 NA      NA
2    Data1 NA  4  0.5000
3    Data2 NA  8  1.0000
4    Data3 NA 16  2.0000
5 Standard  3 NA      NA
6    Data4 NA  9  1.6875
7    Data5 NA 27  5.0625
8    Data6 NA 81 15.1875
```

---

```
f <- function(val)Reduce(\(x,y)if(is.na(y))x else y, val, accumulate = TRUE)
transform(df, D = f(B)* C/16)
         A  B  C       D
1 Standard  2 NA      NA
2    Data1 NA  4  0.5000
3    Data2 NA  8  1.0000
4    Data3 NA 16  2.0000
5 Standard  3 NA      NA
6    Data4 NA  9  1.6875
7    Data5 NA 27  5.0625
8    Data6 NA 81 15.1875
```